# How to get all the results from the nested datatype query in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, lucene

I am trying to fetch all matching sentences from a blob of text using nested datatype of Elasticsearch. In the query mentioned below, I try to filter all the sentence which have "the" and "of" mentioned in the same sentence.

```
GET myindex/doc/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "parent.data",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "match": {
                "parent.data.sentence": "the"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "parent.data.sentence": "of"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Although the response shows, added below, that there are 544 documents in total, only three of them are shown by ES. How can I get to retrieve all of them?

```
{
  "took": 709,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 6,
    "successful": 6,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 73783,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my-index",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "bd9e3c03741956db68fd692a6914e811b0749baaf6565c6385380919f1ce3932",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {},
        "inner_hits": {
          "parent.data.sentence": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 544,
              "max_score": 0,
              "hits": [<response containing 3 sentence>],
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: since you are searching for `the` and `of`, can you please post the mapping and a sample document to see what kind of analyzer you are using and what kind of text that `parent.data.sentence` has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `from` and `size` [options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#_options) to get the desired number of inner hits in response. By default `size` is 3 for inner hits. To increase it to 20 you can update you query as below:

```
GET myindex/doc/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "parent.data",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "match": {
                "parent.data.sentence": "the"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "parent.data.sentence": "of"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {
        "size": 20
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would suggest you to use a combination of `from` and `size` if not all records are to be fetched at once.